# javascript based code editor for custom language syntax

Tags: javascript, editor

I need javascript/html based code editor which I will customize for very simple custom coding language.

This editor tools needs to work in an **offline** solution so the source code must be **downloadable or open**. 
Language syntax will be look like very simplified java script even with out variables
I will define just 'if then' and 'built in function name' for the custom language.

So **it must have configuration support for custom coding language syntax**

If you can refer some ready to use solutions, it will be so helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Plugin for HTML Editor with Syntax Coloring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232764/jquery-plugin-for-html-editor-with-syntax-coloring)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found solution for my own question

I used code mirror

http://codemirror.net/

It has built in support for lots of codding language including JavaScript / C# / VB / C / C++ / CSS / etc

and according the language file you can also modify the supported keywords list