# Coloring CSS syntax for textarea

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm having a page were I edit CSS in a textarea. I would like to have some sort of plugin that colors my code as I edit.

Is there some editor like CKEditor that lets you accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the more number of suggestions  for syntax coloring  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232764/jquery-plugin-for-html-editor-with-syntax-coloring)

Answer (score 2):

there is an editor called [ace](http://ace.ajax.org). It's a multi purpose editor.